# Why must an electric field be Fourier transformed to offer meaningful spectroscopic information?

Tags: optics, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

I understand that it is the mathematical function needed to interpret the data, but this makes no sense to me mathematically.

Why must an electric field (as a function of time) be Fourier transformed to offer meaningful spectroscopic information? In other words:

**Why doesn't a computer simply interpret the raw data, how does the Fourier transformation mathematically make the data easier to interpret?**

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment for OP: Is it easier to think of light in terms of a sum of different colors, or as a very complicated time-dependent electromagnetic field? The color basis is a type of Fourier basis.

Answer (score 2):

Producing the frequency spectrum of a time series is nothing but doing a Fourier transform, that is obtaining the amplitudes (and phases) of sinusoidal waves which result in the time series when all summed together. Given a time series $f(t)$ the Fourier amplitude in frequency space is

$$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt f(t)\:e^{-i \omega t}$$

$F(\omega)$ is in general a complex function (containing not only the amplitude but also the relative phase shift of each wave component at frequency $\omega$). Its absolute value $|F(\omega)|$ is the frequency spectrum and $|F(\omega)|^2$ the power spectrum.

In practice the time dependence is too complicated for a closed mathematical expression to exist for the Fourier transform, so it has to be calculated numerically. Many software packages for so called FFTs (Fast Fourier Transforms) exist. This is essentially what computers are doing when they obtain a spectrum from the raw data.